# React on MAC doesn't work on WINDOWS?

Tags: windows, reactjs, git-bash

I had created a app using a macbook, is working fine on mac. But I try to run this same project on **windows** and doesn't work.

When I run: npm install, I have this feedback:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
    fsevents@^1.1.3 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
    Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
    fsevents@^1.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
    Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
    fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3:
    wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed                             .
```

on my **package.json** I have this:

```
{
  "name": "---",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "styled-components": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I understood that for some reason, I have incompatibility between OS, but this should not be happen, right?

ps: I create a app test using **npx create-react-app my-app** and works! But, why my current project dosent work, WHY, OMG?

ps2: I also try install: **npm i -f** to ignore **WARNs** but **npm start** dosent work, I have same error:

```
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: D:\projetos\cesarcabral\portflio\src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portflio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portflio@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

---

Extra info:

- $ node -v -> v8.9.1
- $ npm -v -> 5.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to install `ajv` :

> npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed

and `src/index.js` is missing.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for answer ... :)

DId install:
'$ npm install ajv@^6.0.0 ajv-keywords@3.1.0
Fine!

and I run again:
'$ npm i

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall D:\projetos\cesarcabral\portflio\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
'

Comment: Some module require [windows-build-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools) to compile native modules. If you want to get rid of the optional dependency warnings, delete *package-lock.json* and *node_modules* folder and install with *--no-optional*